# Make button visible if string visible?

Tags: android, string

I have some text in the strings, and when you swipe your screen, they will change. So I want to make a button visible only, if the 3. text is visible.

```
 <item>for free</item>
                <item>easy to use</item>
                <item>lets start</item>
```

When the "let's start" appears on the screen, I want my button to appear also on the screen, but only, when this string is visible "lets start".

These strings are in a textview, and they coded to change for swipe.

How to make this?

I know we have to implent somehow setVisibillity. and maybe add a listener?

Comment: What are you using to do the swipe? A ViewPager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about comparing current TextView text?

```
if(yourTextView.getText().toString().equals("let's start")){
    yourButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

if i understood correctly that should work.

Comment: So simple, I forgeted this method, It's the easiest way, thanks, next time I try to think more about it.